# Get requests to api stuck on pending

Tags: c#, angular

I apologize in advance for the bad editing skills, I'm new at posting questions

I'm trying to call my c# api from an angular app, however the request is stuck on pending. I don't think theres a mistake in my typescript code but I'm new to c# so it might be something to do with the api, possibly because of the asyncs.

Here's the api code

```
    {
        private static readonly string Tenant = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{azure.tenant}/";
        private static readonly string Resource = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";

        private string getToken()
        {
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Tenant);
            var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(AppId, AppSecret);
            var token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(Resource, clientCredential);
            return token.Result.AccessToken;
        }

        private PowerBIClient getPBIClient()
        {
            var token = new TokenCredentials(getToken(), "Bearer");
            return new PowerBIClient(new Uri("https://api.powerbi.com/"), token);
        }

        public async Task<ODataResponseListReport> getReportsAsync(string ws)
        {
            PowerBIClient pbiClient = getPBIClient();

            var reports = await pbiClient.Reports.GetReportsInGroupAsync(ws);
            return reports;
        }

        public async Task<ReportEmbeddingData> getReportEmbeddingDataAsync(string ws, string rep)
        {
            PowerBIClient pbiClient = getPBIClient();

            var report = await pbiClient.Reports.GetReportInGroupAsync(ws, rep);
            var embedUrl = report.EmbedUrl;
            var reportName = report.Name;

            GenerateTokenRequest genTokenReqParam = new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "view");

            string embedToken = (await pbiClient.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroupAsync(ws, rep, genTokenReqParam)).Token;
            return new ReportEmbeddingData {
                reportId = rep,
                reportName = reportName,
                embedUrl = embedUrl,
                accessToken = embedToken
            };
        }
    }

And here is my angular call that's being done on ngOnInit

getReports(){
    this.http.get("http://localhost:44391/api/Auth?ws="+this.workspaceId)
    .subscribe((response) => {
      this.reportArray = response;
      console.log(this.reportArray);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Do you use .Net MVC Core or .NET MVC for web service? What version? Show controller.

Comment: How are you calling these methods? Show us your action method please.

Comment: @RomaRuzich i'm using .net framework 4.7.2. I'm not sure what you mean by show controller, isn't the code I posted written in the controller file?

Comment: Look https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-simple-web-api-in-asp-net-mvc/ Here describes web api (MVC) or https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/35462/creating-web-api-in-asp-net-core-2-0/part-1---web-api (MVC Core)